# 24 hour time format (so no AM to PM) for fullCalendar

Tags: jquery, time, fullcalendar

I'm trying to display the 24 hour time format in fullCalendar, I'm trying to use these instructions: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/text/timeFormat/

So I've added

```js
timeFormat: {
    agenda: 'H(:mm)' //h:mm{ - h:mm}'
},
```

to json.php :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        editable: true,
        allDayDefault: false,
        events: "core/displays/calendar/json-events.php", 
        defaultView: 'agendaDay',
        timeFormat: {
            agenda: 'H(:mm)' //h:mm{ - h:mm}'
        },
        eventDrop: function(event, delta) {
            alert(event.title + ' was moved ' + delta + ' days\n' + '(should probably update your database)');
        },
        eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {     
            window.location = "details_view.php?id=" + calEvent.id;
        },
        loading: function(bool) {
            if (bool)
                $('#loading').show();
            else
                $('#loading').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

but that didn't work, so I've added to fullCalendar.js

```js
// time formats
titleFormat: {
    month: 'MMMM yyyy',
    week: "MMM d[ yyyy]{ '&#8212;'[ MMM] d yyyy}",
    day: 'dddd, MMM d, yyyy'
},
columnFormat: {
    month: 'ddd',
    week: 'ddd M/d',
    day: 'dddd M/d'
},
axisFormat: 'H(:mm)', //,'h(:mm)tt',
timeFormat: {
    agenda: 'H(:mm)' //h:mm{ - h:mm}'
},
// locale
```

but that didn't work either, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You want to set the layout to 24 hour system or the events.

If you want to add to the events, put like 22:00 'party' then add   timeFormat: 'H:mm' , to your json.php file.

```
eventDrop: function (event, delta) {
        alert(event.title + ' was moved ' + delta + ' days\n' +
            '(should probably update your database)');
},
timeFormat: 'H:mm',
```

If you want to change the layout of your calendar then just go to your  fullCalendar.js

Look up:

**setDefaults**

And change your code like the following.

```
setDefaults({
    allDaySlot: true,
    allDayText: 'Volledige dag',
    firstHour: 8,
    slotMinutes: 30,
    defaultEventMinutes: 120,
    axisFormat: 'HH:mm',
    timeFormat: {
        agenda: 'H:mm{ - h:mm}'
    },
    dragOpacity: {
        agenda: .5
    },
    minTime: 0,
    maxTime: 24
});
```

Answer (score 33):

This option works now for me in fullCalendar v2 :

```
slotLabelFormat:"HH:mm"
```

http://fullcalendar.io/docs/agenda/slotLabelFormat/

Comment: slotLabelFormat is not available til v3

Comment: `slotLabelFormat: {hour: 'numeric', minute: '2-digit', hour12: false}` for version v5.10.2

Answer (score 14):

im using version 4.2.0 and it worked with this at the end of events :

```
      {
      title: 'Birthday Party',
      start: '2019-06-13T07:00:00',
      eventBackgroundColor: '#ff0000',
      allDay:false
      }

  ],
  eventTimeFormat: { 
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit',
    hour12:false
}

});
```

Comment: this works good !!... Should have been more easily understandable in _docs_ though, Found it [_now_](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventTimeFormat) using your good answer..   Thnx

Comment: Thanks, I'm using 5.4.0 version and it worked too!

Answer (score 11):

As of fullCalendar.io version 4, depending on where you want the format to change, use [eventTimeFormat](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventTimeFormat), [titleFormat](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/titleFormat), [columnHeaderFormat](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/columnHeaderFormat) or [slotLabelFormat](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotLabelFormat) (last one for the axis in timegrids) in the following form :

```
eventTimeFormat: {
  hour: '2-digit', //2-digit, numeric
  minute: '2-digit', //2-digit, numeric
  second: '2-digit', //2-digit, numeric
  meridiem: false, //lowercase, short, narrow, false (display of AM/PM)
  hour12: false //true, false
}
```

The comments display the value options.

For more reference: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-formatting

Comment: This works only for event boxes, not for grid labels (and you're missing "," after the first false

Answer (score 10):

With v.4 something like this was necessary for me to achieve 24-hours format:

```
slotLabelFormat: {hour: 'numeric', minute: '2-digit', hour12: false}
```

Answer (score 9):

If you wanna change the month view in 24H search and change in fullcalendar.js this:

```
var dateFormatters = {
    s   : function(d)   { return d.getSeconds() },
    ss  : function(d)   { return zeroPad(d.getSeconds()) },
    m   : function(d)   { return d.getMinutes() },
    mm  : function(d)   { return zeroPad(d.getMinutes()) },
    h   : function(d)   { return d.getHours() % 24 || 24 },             //modificato : era 12 al posto di 24
    hh  : function(d)   { return zeroPad(d.getHours() % 24 || 24) },    //modificato : era 12 al posto di 24
    H   : function(d)   { return d.getHours() },
    HH  : function(d)   { return zeroPad(d.getHours()) },
    d   : function(d)   { return d.getDate() },
    dd  : function(d)   { return zeroPad(d.getDate()) },
    ddd : function(d,o) { return o.dayNamesShort[d.getDay()] },
    dddd: function(d,o) { return o.dayNames[d.getDay()] },
    M   : function(d)   { return d.getMonth() + 1 },
    MM  : function(d)   { return zeroPad(d.getMonth() + 1) },
    MMM : function(d,o) { return o.monthNamesShort[d.getMonth()] },
    MMMM: function(d,o) { return o.monthNames[d.getMonth()] },
    yy  : function(d)   { return (d.getFullYear()+'').substring(2) },
    yyyy: function(d)   { return d.getFullYear() },
    //t : function(d)   { return d.getHours() < 12 ? 'a' : 'p' },
    //tt    : function(d)   { return d.getHours() < 12 ? 'am' : 'pm' },
    //T : function(d)   { return d.getHours() < 12 ? 'A' : 'P' },
    //TT    : function(d)   { return d.getHours() < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM' },
    t   : function(d)   { return d.getMinutes() == 0 ? ':00' : '' },
    tt  : function(d)   { return d.getHours() < 12 ? '' : '' },
    T   : function(d)   { return d.getHours() < 12 ? '' : '' },
    TT  : function(d)   { return d.getHours() < 12 ? '' : '' },
    u   : function(d)   { return formatDate(d, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'") },
    S   : function(d)   {
        var date = d.getDate();
        if (date > 10 && date < 20) {
            return 'th';
        }
        return ['st', 'nd', 'rd'][date%10-1] || 'th';
    }
};
```

Answer (score 7):

The most upvoted answer works for older versions.
For newer versions add another variable in `SetDefaults`:

```
slotLabelFormat:'H(:mm)',
```

This should work for newer versions (2018), like FullCalendar v3.9.0

Comment: gives me "t.cmdFormatter is not a function" in v4

Answer (score 3):

in v4 for vue.js

```
<div>    
    <FullCalendar

       [...] // some code

       :eventTimeFormat="{
             hour: '2-digit',
             minute: '2-digit',
             hour12: false
       }"
    />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

With v.5 something like this was necessary for me to achieve 24-hours format:

```
<FullCalendar
    eventTimeFormat={{
        hour: '2-digit',
        minute: '2-digit',
        hour12: false
    }}
    slotLabelFormat={{
        hour: 'numeric',
        minute: '2-digit',
        hour12: false
    }}
>
```

`eventTimeFormat` put agenda label on 24-hours.
`slotLabelFormat` put slot on 24-hours.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using fullCalendar v1, you should try adding these:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
     [...]// some code,

     axisFormat: 'H:mm',
     timeFormat: {
          agenda: 'H:mm{ - H:mm}'
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason these solutions didn’t worked for me anymore.

So after some extensive (cmd+F) search I found this post talking about /includes/js/main.js around line 107. Line 107 lets you change the day/month/year order.

But then! Line 113 (or around) lets you change am/pm, in week and day agenda view, into a time representation which is used by the whole world (except some English speaking countries).

You can change more if you like, but below you'll find the piece code that was good enough for me to have it shown correctly on a Dutch website.

`TT:function(a){return a.getHours()<12?"AM":"PM"},u:function(a){return Oa(a,"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")},S:function(a){a=a.getDate();if(a>10&&a<20)return"th";return["st","nd","rd"][a%10-1]||"th"}};Aa.applyAll=$a;Ja.month=mc;Ja.basicWeek=nc;Ja.basicDay=oc;wb({weekMode:"fixed"});Ja.agendaWeek=qc;Ja.agendaDay=rc;wb({allDaySlot:true,allDayText:"hele dag",firstHour:8,slotMinutes:30,defaultEventMinutes:120,axisFormat:"HH:mm",timeFormat:{agenda:"h:mm{ - h:mm}"},dragOpacity:{agenda:0.5},minTime:0,
maxTime:22})})`

And for your convenience you'll find here the whole main.js fixed for Dutch: http://pastebin.com/HYGHRebZ

I hope this solution will work also for you!

Answer (score 1):

use this for  v.2 plus`timeFormat: 'H(:mm)',`

Answer (score 1):

```
axisFormat: 'H:mm',
timeFormat: {
    agenda: 'H:mm'
},
```

it is working on both `agendaDay` view and event show 24 hr format

Answer (score 0):

in v4, you can set the calendar option programmatically to achieve the 24h format for the hour label on the left of the grid:

```
const slotLabelOption = {
    hour: 'numeric',
    minute: '2-digit',
    omitZeroMinute: false,
    meridiem: 'narrow',
    hour12: false
};
calendar.setOption('slotLabelFormat', slotLabelOption);
```

For the event time do the same:

```
 const eventTimeOption = {
        hour: 'numeric',
        minute: '2-digit',
        omitZeroMinute: false,
        meridiem: 'narrow',
        hour12: false
    };
 calendar.setOption('eventTimeFormat', eventTimeOption);
```

with calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(....) //however you initialize it

Answer (score 0):

try this and its will work

```
1 - first thing :
```

add  this line to your options

```
locale: 'en-GB',
```

and its will start from 0 ... 24

```
2 - second thing :
```

and add this line

```
 slotLabelFormat:
                    {
                        hour: 'numeric',
                        minute: '2-digit',
                        omitZeroMinute: false,
                    },
```

inside slotLabelFormat you  can customize time in your calendar
now its will start from 00:00 .... 23:00