# how to validate 24 hour formated Time in Jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, validation, time

I want to validate 24 hour formatted Time, Time is in the following format.

```
HH:MM:SS
```

How could i go for it. Please help me.
My HTMl Code is

```
    <asp:TextBox Width="120px" MaxLength="20" ID="txtEndTime" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                <ajaxctrl:maskededitextender id="metxtEndTime" runat="server" targetcontrolid="txtEndTime"
                                    mask="99:99:99" messagevalidatortip="true" masktype="Number" inputdirection="LeftToRight"
                                    clearmaskonlostfocus="false" acceptnegative="None" errortooltipenabled="True" />
```

Comment: Validate? As in HH < 24 && HH >= 0 && MM > 0 && MM < 60 && SS > 0 && SS < 60?

Comment: also check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9080944/24-hour-time-format-so-no-am-to-pm-for-fullcalendar

Comment: Valid means values.. hours can not be more than 24, mins can not be greater than 60, same for Seconds

Comment: Hours might be 0 to 24 or limited to 23 depending on how you want to show midnight. Minutes should be 0 to 59, seconds should be 0 - 59 but can be 60 if you allow leap seconds.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To only validate the format, you can use this:

```
var valid = (timeStr.search(/^\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$/) != -1);
```

If you're trying to validate the values as well, you can try this:

```
var valid = (timeStr.search(/^\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$/) != -1) &&
            (timeStr.substr(0,2) >= 0 && timeStr.substr(0,2) <= 24) &&
            (timeStr.substr(3,2) >= 0 && timeStr.substr(3,2) <= 59) &&
            (timeStr.substr(6,2) >= 0 && timeStr.substr(6,2) <= 59);
```

Comment: That would validate the format, but not the values, would it?

Comment: @ATaylor - Yes, that's correct. Wasn't sure if he wanted the values checked as well.

Comment: Thanks jeff for great help

Answer (score 6):

A different approach, but using an extra javascript lib:

```
var valid = moment(timeStr, "HH:mm:ss", true).isValid();
```

I guess if you already use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) in your project, there's no downside.

Answer (score 3):

A good pattern for this task would be

```
/^(?:[01]\d|2[0-3]):(?:[0-5]\d):(?:[0-5]\d)$/.test(document.getElementById("metxtEndTime").value);
```

That regex could be used in the HTML5 `pattern` attribute of input elements, but I didn't try it yet.

Answer (score 2):

To validate the format and values:

```
// Allows times like 24:05:00
function validateTime(s) {
  var t = s.split(':');

  return /^\d\d:\d\d:\d\d$/.test(s) &&
         t[0] >= 0 && t[0] < 25 &&
         t[1] >= 0 && t[1] < 60 &&
         t[2] >= 0 && t[2] < 60;
}
```

Depends if you want to allow values like 24:00:00 for midnight and say 24:15:00 as 15 minutes past midnight.

Answer (score 0):

This approach is straightforward and accounts for 24:01 as invalid. The "id" is the id in an input statement in the php code so that the colon (:) can be inserted and written back into a time.

```
function checkTime(str,id){
    if (str.length == 0) return true;
    if (str.length < 4)  return false;
    var x = str.indexOf(":");
    if (x < 0){
        str = str.substr(0,2)+":"+str.substr(2,2);
        document.getElementById(id).value = str;
        document.getElementById(id).focus();
        return true;
     }  
    if (
        (str.substr(0,2) >= 0 ) && 
        (str.substr(0,2) <= 24) &&
        (str.substr(3,2) >= 0 ) && 
        (str.substr(3,2) <= 59) &&
        (str.substr(0,2) < 24 || (str.substr(0,2) == 24 && str.substr(3,2) == 0))
        )
        return true;
    return false;
}
```