# How to ask for Time using Full Calendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I have gone over several of the questions here about fullCalendar or their documentation on the official site, but have yet to find how can I ask the user to add the time, not just the day. Right now all I get is 06-19-2017 but I can't get fullCalendar to ask for the time of day since the events are time based and day based. The end result should be 06-19-2017 1:30 PM with fullCalendar asking for the time and showing it in a 12 Hour format. The 12 hour format was already answered here [24 hour time format (so no AM to PM) for fullCalendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9080944/24-hour-time-format-so-no-am-to-pm-for-fullcalendar) but I can't get fullCalendar to ask for the time.

Comment: how are you getting user input exactly? There's nothing in fullCalendar to my knowledge which actively "asks" for a day or time. However using the "select" callback the user can drag and drop the event to the exact time they want (on any of the "agenda" style views). https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/select_callback/

Comment: Hi @ADyson, right now it's just me highlighting multiple days or clicking on a single day (This is only the date). What am looking for is a way to ask for the time or to be able to add the time to it.

Comment: what view are you using? If you use agendaWeek or agendaDay then you can click-and-drag to highlight the exact times. Then the "start" and "end" dates/times of the dragged area will be passed as the "start" and "end" parameters of the "select" callback. If you use month view, or the "basic" style views then you can't select specific times by this method.

Comment: @ADyson Let me check that out today .Thank you.